# Dynamically nested $resource Promises with ordered $q.all Promises

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

**2nd UPDATE**

We are implementing a **BulkEdit** functionality which sends **async CRUD requests** to a Backend.

So what I require here is a **dynamically created set of nested promises**.

In an abstract version the data array could look like:

```
   var objArr = [
    {
      name: 'A',
      subs: [
        {
          id: 1,
          _action: 'create'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          _action: 'create'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          _action: 'delete'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      subs: [
        {
          id: 4,
          _action: 'create'
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          _action: 'put'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'C',
      subs: []
    }
  ];
```

I try to illustrate how the requests should be sent for this data following the order given by '_action'.

1. Get some transaction ID (see below)
2. As soon as transaction ID is there start to send requests for every Object in the Array given the following rules:

   - Per Object send all 'delete' requests at once if there are any.
   - After that or if there weren't any 'delete' requests send all 'put'
     requests if there are any.
   - After 'delete' and/or 'put' send all 'create' requests if there are any.
3. As soon as all requests for an Object are done, do something per Object.
4. As soon as all Objects are done, close the Transaction.

[image: Illustrative Request Flow]

How is it possible to create this **dynamic nested/non-nested** promise chain?

**UPDATED CODE** **contains now Promise Creation**

When calling the function below, first a TransactionService gets a transaction id which is required to be sent with each request. When everything is successful, the Transaction will be closed.

My current issue is that promises are not resolved in the correct order (while the OPTIONS preflight requests seem to be) and that this example  creates Promises even if they are not required (e.g. for Object 'C' in the example above).

```
function startIt(objArr) {

  TransactionService.getTransaction().then(function (transaction) {

    var promiseArray = MyService.submit(objArr, transaction.id);

    $q.all(promiseArray).then(function () {

      Transactions.closeTransaction(transaction.id, function () {}).then(function () {

      });
    };
  });
}
```

This is the function for 'submit':

```
 function submit(objArr, transactionId) {

  var promises = objArr.map(function (obj) {
    return submitWithTransId(transactionId, obj)
      .then(function (response) {
         // Object done
      });
  });

  return promises;
}
```

And this function is actually creating the Promises:

```
function submitWithTransId(transactionId, obj) {

  var promisesDelete = [];
  var promisesUpdate = [];
  var promisesCreate = [];

  angular.forEach(obj['subs'], function (sub) {

      switch (sub._action) {
        case 'delete':
          promisesDelete.push(createPromise(sub, bulktransactionId));
          break;
        case 'put':
          promisesUpdate.push(createPromise(sub, bulktransactionId));
          break;
        case 'create':
          promisesCreate.push(createPromise(sub, bulktransactionId));
          break;
    }
  });

  var chainedPromises = $q.all(promisesDelete).then(function (deleteResponse) {
      return $q.all(promisesUpdate).then(function (updateResponse) {
        return $q.all(promisesCreate).then(function (createResponse) {
        });
      });
    });

  return chainedPromises;
```

And this is my `createPromise` function:

```
/** only simplified handling create case **/

function createPromise(sub, bulktransactionId) {

var queryParams = {};
if (bulktransactionId !== undefined && bulktransactionId !== null) {
   queryParams.transaction_id = bulktransactionId;
}

var promise = MyResourceService.create(queryParams, sub).$promise;
promise.then(function (newSub) {
    // do something with the new/updated/deleted sub, especially update view model
 });
 return promise;
}

/** MyResourceService **/
return $resource(ENV.apiEndpoint + 'api/v1/subs/:_id',
 {
  _id: '@id'
 }, {
  create: {
   method: 'POST'
  }
 }
);
```

Comment: Could you split this into two arrays, then process all the deletes first, when all those promises are done, process the rest?

Comment: Maybe build two arrays of promises, one for creates and one for deletes. Then you could do something like Promise.all(deletes).then(function(){Promise.all(creates);}(

Comment: yes, I could do so, but then it's not executed 'per object' which is steering some *object 'A' done* process :-(

Comment: @LBA to get around that you could just build an array of objects containing their own promise array.

Comment: @BrianGlaz, you're probably right, but that's exactly where I am a bit stuck as a mainly PHP guy :-(

Comment: @LBA - Did you had a look at the solution?

Comment: @nikhil, please see my updated question :-(

Comment: @LBA - `var promiseArray` in question can be replaced by `var promises` of my solution and I think that should be it.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the following solution. The objective is to provide you some sort of structure. Please see, you will have to modify to your use.

```
 var objArr = [{
        name: 'A',
        subs: [{
                id: 1,
                _action: 'create'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                _action: 'create'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                _action: 'delete'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        subs: [{
                id: 4,
                _action: 'create'
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                _action: 'put'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        subs: []
    }
];



var promises = objArr.map(function(obj) {
    return firstLevelPromise(obj)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response); // promise for each object
            return response;
        });
});

$q.all(promises)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response); // completion - close transaction
    });


function firstLevelPromise(obj) {
    var deletePromises = [];
    var putPromies = [];
    var insertPromies = [];

    obj.subs.forEach(function(sub) { // Preparing promises array for delete, put and insert
        if (sub._action === "delete") {
            deletePromises.push(deletePromise(sub));
        } else if (sub._action === "put") {
            putPromies.push(putPromise(sub));
        } else {
            insertPromies.push(insertPromise(sub));
        }
    });

    return $q.all(deletePromises) // executing delete promises
    .then(function(deleteResponse) {
        console.log("deleteExecuted: " + obj.name);
        return $q.all(putPromies) // on completion of delete, execute put promies
            .then(function(putResponse) {
                console.log("putExecuted: " + obj.name);
                return $q.all(insertPromies) // on completion of put, execute insert promises
                    .then(function(insertResponse) {
                        console.log("insertExecuted: " + obj.name);
                        return "object promise completed: " + obj.name; // on completion, return
                    });
            });
    });
}

function deletePromise(task) {
    return $q.resolve(task); // write your delete code here
}

function putPromise(task) {
    return $q.resolve(task); // write your put code here
}

function insertPromise(task) {
    return $q.resolve(task); // write your insert code here
}
```

Please note, the above code will do the following

- Prepare a collection of promises where there is one promise for each object in objectArray
- Each promise will have promises chain i.e. delete promises, followed by put promises and finally followed by insert promises i.e. it ensures that for each object perform the delete tasks, then on completion perform the put tasks and then on its completion perform the insert tasks.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kR8YMfmL2UaHA0OodOOQ?p=preview) and documentation for [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

**UPDATE**

The problem is with the `createPromise` function only. Update your code to following. The problem was that you are calling the `then` before returning, hence, it is likely that the you are returning a resolved promise like `$q.resolve()`. In this case, it is possible that a `create` request gets resolved before `delete` or `put` and a `put` calls gets resolved before `delete`. Hence, you should return the promise from here and perform the post action things in the `$q.all` block.

```
function createPromise(sub, bulktransactionId) {

    var queryParams = {};
    if (bulktransactionId !== undefined && bulktransactionId !== null) {
       queryParams.transaction_id = bulktransactionId;
    }
    return MyResourceService.create(queryParams, sub).$promise;
}
```

Comment: I am really trying to understand and apply it to my code. currently without any success. but i'll try further.

Comment: Okay. Let me know if you get stuck somewhere

Comment: thanks, if I understood your question right your solution is creating promises per 'action' but not per 'object' per 'action', I'll update my question again trying to be even more precise.

Comment: I don't get in running in my code. now I see with console.logs that the order seems to be right and in my network traffic that the 'OPTIONS' preflight requests seem to be in the right order, but still with my test data it still fails with 'CREATE' before 'DELETE'. I am a bit desparate.

Comment: @LBA - I hope when you say CREATE before DELETE, then those items are from same `sub`?

Comment: Also, noticed that in JSON you have delete, create and put but your switch case has remove, create and update. This is an issue for sure if it is not just typos

Comment: please see my updated code - i don't see anymore where my code differs from yours

Comment: @LBA - Agreed. Both the code looks alike. However, is the CREATE before DELETE applies within one sub or is it like CREATE of item in one sub is coming before DELETE of item from another sub?

Comment: It happens for one sub, otherwise it wouldnt be an issue and totally ok.

Comment: @LBA - Then it seems to be correct until and unless there is some issue in `createPromise` function. Can you please add `createPromise` function as well?

Comment: I agree with @nikhil. There is certainly some issue with `createPromise` function that OP is using to populate `promisesDelete`, `promisesUpdate` and `promisesCreate` arrays. Also, @LBA how are you referring `bulktransactionId` while calling it? Shouldn't it be `transactionId` instead?

Comment: @nikhil and @NLN thanks for you support. `createPromise` simply returns (after a bit complex factoring) $resource $promise. - What I saw in my code is that all PREFLIGHT Options requests seem to be sent in the right order - is it possible that $q.all is getting resolved after the OPTIONS request already?

Comment: @NLN, I updated my question with the code you requested as well

Comment: @LBA - Please check the updated answer. As suspected, the problem was in the `createPromse` function. Please see whether the above works for you.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately even totally removing the `.then` after creation of the promise does not change the behaviour :-(

Comment: @LBA - As we have tested every component independently, can we also test `MyResourceService.create` by replacing it will a simple `$http`? Also, can you reproduce the error somewhere where I can dig into it?

Comment: @nikhil, I found it, thanks, gave you the bounty, please see my self-given answer.

Comment: @LBA - I am glad that finally the problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this - the trick is to accumulate the promise (that's what I'm using the `reduce` for. Hope it helps.

```
// reversed the order => delete actions first; otherwise you may have to do extra logic may be needed
var objArr = [ 
   { name: 'A', 
     subs: [
        { id: null,
          _action: 'delete'
        }, 
        { id: 2,
          _action: 'create']
        }
   },
   { name: 'B',
     subs: [
        { id: 3.
          _action: 'create'
        }
     ]
 ];

 Promise.all(objArr.map(obj => {
   return obj.subs.reduce((accumulatedPromisedSub, sub) => {
     return accumulatedPromisedSub.then(_ => yourRequestCallHere(sub) )
   },
   Promise.resolve(true) // you could also do your delete here if you like
   )
 }))

// OR going sort order agnostic:

 Promise.all(objArr.map(obj => {
   const deleteAction = obj.subs.find(sub => sub._action === 'delete');

   return obj.subs.reduce((accumulatedPromisedSub, sub) => {
     if (sub._action === 'delete') return accumulatedPromisedSub;
     return accumulatedPromisedSub.then(_ => yourRequestCallHere(sub) )
   },
   deleteAction ? yourRequestCall(deleteAction) : Promise.resolve(true)
   )
 }))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am so happy and thankful, I found it.

To my understanding I had two main issues in my code.

As `$resource` is not providing a (please forgive me, pros!) *real*  `$promise` even when I use something like `.get().$promise` I had to

1. use `bind` to map the **createPromise** function to my arrays
2. do the mapping only directly before returning the `$q.all` promise.

In any other case `$resource` seemed to immediately fill its promise with an empty object and `$q.all` did not work anymore as promises looked like they where resolved.

Special thanks to @nikhil who supported me in finding this ugly complex thing and who earned the bounty.

This is the working snippet:

```
function submitWithTransId(transactionId, obj) {

 var arrayDelete = [];
 var arrayUpdate = [];
 var arrayCreate = [];

 angular.forEach(obj['subs'], function (sub) {

   switch (sub._action) {
     case 'delete':
       arrayDelete.push(sub);
       break;
     case 'update':
       arrayUpdate.push(sub);
       break;
     case 'create':
       arrayCreate.push(sub);
       break;
    }
 });

 var promisesDelete = flattenArray(arrayDelete.map(createPromise.bind(undefined, obj, transactionId)));

 return $q.all(promisesDelete).then(function (deleteResponse) {

    console.log('Delete Promises ' + obj.name + ' resolved');

    var promisesUpdate = flattenArray(arrayUpdate.map(createPromise.bind(undefined, obj, transactionId)));

    return $q.all(promisesUpdate).then(function (updateResponse) {
      var promisesCreate = flattenArray(arrayCreate.map(createPromise.bind(undefined, obj, transactionId)));

      console.log('Update Promises ' + obj.name + ' resolved');

      return $q.all(promisesCreate).then(function (createResponse) {

        console.log('Create Promises ' + obj.name + ' resolved');

      });
    });
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Catched an error: ');
    console.log(error);
  });
```

});